# Parsing a .txt file using Lua. The most basic of parsing

Tags: parsing, lua

I am currently trying to parse a file. it looks like this:

```
A|00CA|GOLDSTONE GTS|35350525|-116888367|3038
R|04|37|6000|0|0|0|35349333|-116893334|3038|300|50
R|22|217|6000|0|0|0|35360333|-116877500|3038|300|50

A|00WI|NORTHERN LITE|44304283|-89050111|860
R|09|90|1000|0|0|0|44304217|-89052022|860|300|50
R|27|270|1000|0|0|0|44304350|-89048208|860|300|50

A|01ID|LAVA HOT SPRINGS|42608250|-112032461|5268
R|14|143|2894|0|0|0|42611000|-112034867|5268|300|50
R|32|323|2894|0|0|0|42603733|-112030533|5268|300|50

A|01LS|COUNTRY BREEZE|30722639|-91077361|125
R|09|91|1800|0|0|0|30722747|-91080222|125|300|50
R|27|271|1800|0|0|0|30722531|-91074500|125|300|50

A|01MT|CRYSTAL LAKES RESORT|48789131|-114880436|3141
R|13|131|5000|0|0|0|48794975|-114885842|3141|300|50
R|31|311|5000|0|0|0|48783292|-114875003|3141|300|50
```

but longer, however you get the picture.

Say I want to get a whole line out of this using only the a four digit code.

So when the user types in 00CA it will pull the following whole line and break it up into the numbers or letter in between the "|":

```
A|00CA|GOLDSTONE GTS|35350525|-116888367|3038
```

I have been given code that looks like this:

```
file = assert(io.open("Airports.txt", "r"))
for line in file:lines() do
  fields = { line:match "(%w+)|(%w+)|([%w ]+)|([%d-]+)|([%d-]+)|([%d-]+)" }
  print(fields[4], fields[5])  -- the 2 numeric fields you're interested in
end
file:close()
```

Of this whole line:

```
A|00CA|GOLDSTONE GTS|35350525|-116888367|3038
```

I would only be interested in getting these peices of data : 35350525 : -116888367

however when I try and put this or anything like this. It just puts out a nil value.

```
-- ICAO == "00CA"
fields = { line:match "(%w+)|" .. ICAO .. "|([%w ]+)|([%d-]+)|([%d-]+)|([%d-]+)" }
```

And obviously you I need to put some custom data (The ICAO code) in there as many of the lines follow that pattern.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The title does not reflect the question.

Comment: @user2609216 The pattern I gave for your other question is still pretty general since I don't know all the possible formats of your input. You can make the pattern even more specific if you know for sure a field can't have more than *x* characters. Check out **[Lua Ref manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1)** for other character classes you can use. For example, if you know first field can only have a single uppercase letter, you can replace `(%w+)` with `(%u)`.

Comment: Did you try my last comment suggestion in the other question? Specifically http://pastebin.com/v9RPy27G.

Comment: Yes sorry, i only posted this because I lost the first question. Please ignore this topic! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add parentheses around the call:

```
line:match("(%w+)|" .. ICAO .. "|([%w ]+)|([%d-]+)|([%d-]+)|([%d-]+)")
```

The original code is parsed as

```
(line:match "(%w+)|") .. ICAO .. "|([%w ]+)|([%d-]+)|([%d-]+)|([%d-]+)"
```

Here is the complete code that I tested:

```
line="A|00CA|GOLDSTONE GTS|35350525|-116888367|3038"
ICAO = "00CA"
print(line:match("(%w+)|" .. ICAO .. "|([%w ]+)|([%d-]+)|([%d-]+)|([%d-]+)"))
```

The output is

```
A   GOLDSTONE GTS   35350525    -116888367  3038
```

For this task, I'd use a simpler pattern: `"(.-)|" .. ICAO .. "|(.-)|(.-)|(.-)|(.-)$"`

Comment: That doesn't work. It finds a nil value. is the syntax correct for this? 

It seems that as soon as i put a value that isn't a "wildcard", it puts out a nil value. Is there something about line:match that says you can't have anything but (%w+) type text in the call?

Comment: @user2609216: Maybe you should take some time to learn how [Lua patterns and pattern matching works](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1).

Comment: @user2609216, it works for me; see the complete code in my edited answer.